# Chrome extensions and bookmarks disabled using Brackets.io

Tags: google-chrome, adobe-brackets, live-preview

*The question is regarding Bracket.io with Chrome as the default browser.*

When using the option "Live Preview" Chrome browser opens with the live document, but does not show me the extensions and bookmarks that I have installed on my browser.

This is when Chrome opens Brackets Live Preview:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsHrs.png]

This is when I open it myself (with extensions and bookmarks but without automatic updates), which is how I would like to have it:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE40y.png]

How I set it to open Chrome with my bookmarks and extensions?

Answer (score 2):

Brackets Live Preview uses a separate Chrome profile from your regular copy of Chrome. It starts out as a completely clean new profile, so it won't have any of your regular bookmarks, etc. But Live Preview reuses that same profile on each subsequent launch -- so if you *add* bookmarks to the window Live Preview is running in, they'll reappear the next time you use Live Preview.

There are a couple good reasons for this, and also one way to work around it that's become available recently.

Quoting from my answer to ["Why does Brackets open a new instance of chrome when using Live Editor?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089422/why-does-bracketsword-editor-open-a-new-instance-of-chrome-when-using-live-edi/29093296#29093296):

> The Chrome profile that Brackets launches for Live Preview has the
>   [Chrome Remote Debugging
>   API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol)
>   enabled. There are two reasons Brackets uses a separate profile for
>   this:
>
> - Remote Debugging is off by default, and enabling it requires re-launching Chrome. Using a separate profile means your existing
>     browsing session doesn't have to be restarted, which would be
>     disruptive if you have lots of tabs open.
> - It reduces security slightly -- other processes *on your local machine* could use the Remote Debugging API to monitor / interfere
>     with other browsing you do in this Chrome window. (The API is *not*
>     exposed to the network, so if you trust your computer to be
>     malware-free, this is less of a concern).
>
> If you don't like having to open a separate Chrome window, you can
>   check *File > Enable Experimental Live Preview* to try out a new Live
>   Preview implementation that doesn't require the Remote Debugging API,
>   and thus doesn't launch a new copy of Chrome. You can't use this
>   option if your project has a custom server URL set, though.

Comment: After checking `File > Enable Experimental Live Preview` .. that made Brackets use my default Browser instead of always using Chrome.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, as it sets various flags needed for remote debugging.

See this issue report on GitHub: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/8653

Comment: I understand, then there is no way to do this?

The first time I used LivePreview, I opened without an extension or markers alone when I do it again I get only Skype (and I have many others), if they can not show any marker, if shown the Grafting of Skype?

How I can make you hide it and not show anything?

Answer (score 0):

In your first Chrome Browser : If you don't have chrome account, please SignUp and Login. All of your Chrome Preference will be save in your account.

Then, in Brackets's Chrome Browser you have to login to Show all of your Chrome extensions 
 & Bookmarks.