# Why does Brackets (code editor) open a new instance of Chrome when using Live Editor?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, adobe-brackets

In this new instance of Chrome, all of my accounts are signed out and I have to relog in. In the task bar I can see the original Chrome and I can open them side by side.

The old instance of Chrome:

- All my apps
- Accounts signed in

The new Live Preview instance of Chrome:

- I dont have any of my apps
- No accounts signed in
- Essentially it is as if I am using Chrome for the first time

What I am asking is, is it safe to sign into my accounts on this new instance of Chrome?

Answer (score 4):

The Chrome profile that Brackets launches for Live Preview has the [Chrome Remote Debugging API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol) enabled. There are two reasons Brackets uses a separate profile for this:

- Remote Debugging is off by default, and enabling it requires re-launching Chrome. Using a separate profile means your existing browsing session doesn't have to be restarted, which would be disruptive if you have lots of tabs open.
- It reduces security slightly -- other processes *on your local machine* could use the Remote Debugging API to monitor / interfere with other browsing you do in this Chrome window. (The API is *not* exposed to the network, so if you trust your computer to be malware-free, this is less of a concern).

If you don't like having to open a separate Chrome window, you can check *File > Enable Experimental Live Preview* to try out a new Live Preview implementation that doesn't require the Remote Debugging API, and thus doesn't launch a new copy of Chrome. You can't use this option if your project has a custom server URL set, though.

Comment: just the answer I was looking for... Thank you